# Tab key does not change focus to another input box using Windows API in Go

Tags: windows, go, winapi

I have a windows tray which is use to create a task for another user. The tray pops up a window which has a bunch of fields like FirstName, LastName, ect,

When I type a FirstName I try to use TAB key to change the focus to LastName. But Tab is not working.

I am using windows.NewLazySystemDLL("User32.dll") to load the user32 and then create child windows by passing properties which include windowStyle as WS_TABSTOP.

Thanks in Advance

I tried using various options in Go including providing parent window, using WS_GROUP to create group of child windows.

Comment: Tabbing through controls only works automatically for dialogs. For non-dialogs you have to either add a call to IsDialogMessage or handle the VK_TAB key yourself.

Comment: IsDialogMessage is needed for dialogs as well, it doesn't work automatically.

Comment: Thanks @SoronelHaetir and @JonathanPotter! By any chance you have any code snippets example that I can refer.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir Solution worked with IsDialogMessage to translate the message and VK_TAB to identify Tab is pressed with wParam for me.

Answer (score 0):

@SoronelHaetir Solution worked with IsDialogMessage to translate the message and VK_TAB to identify Tab is pressed with wParam for me.